# Why is the diagonal part of a matrix,A, a polynomial in A?

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm sure this is pretty standard but I haven't been able to find it any books.  In the Jordan decomposition of a matrix $A=D+N$ into a diagonal, $D$ and nilpotent $N$, why is it that $D= p(A)$ where $p$ is a polynomial without constant term?  Thanks.